# Rails takes forever to load first page on Beaglebone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Ruby 2.3.1, Rails 5.1.5, Devise 4.4.3.

Background: I have a Beaglebone (Linux) running a simple API-style Rails app. The user logs in via an external page to Devise, then Rails renders its first view: `workflows#index`.

Expected: after the correct credentials are submitted, the server should render `workflows#index` in less than 2 seconds.

Actual: Every time I reboot, this first render takes anywhere from **80 seconds (dev) - 100 seconds (production)** (99% of that on views) the first time. The Beaglebone isn't this slow - most views are rendered in less than 0.5s, including `workflows#index` on every reload.

Things I have tried:

- Add `config.assets.digest = false` and `config.assets.debug = false` in development.rb as I was loading the dev server. No improvement.
- Discovered that an early partial called `_banner.html.erb` was taking nearly all the time. After analyzing `_banner`, I saw that it was loading an image. I removed the image. Now, the server still takes 80+s but `_banner` is loading in <1s, indicating that the existence of the image wasn't the problem but that the issue may have something to do with assets.
- Eliminate nearly all HTML from `workflows#index` to see if it is causing the slow load. No improvement.
- Switch to production server in case it's environment-based. This time, it takes 100s.

Causes eliminated:

- Not the GUI / browser. Why: the GUI / browser has successfully shown an HTML+CSS+JS page before the first call to Rails occurs.
- Not the development environment settings (possibly). Why: production server has the same problem.
- Not an issue loading text or images in the DOM. Why: removing almost everything from workflows#index made no difference.

Comment: Profile it--but BB *is* slow on IO, and Rails startup machinations aren't particularly speedy. But without any info about your app it's impossible to say--check your env config, check your initializers, your caching, all the normal Rails stuff. IMO it shouldn't take that long, but I've never tried it on a BB, just RPi.

Comment: @DaveNewton To give more detail on what I mentioned, every page on the app loads in under a second, including pages that involve heavier processing and more complex views.

Comment: Making progress - I think it may have something to do with Rails building up its cache the first time after the repo is transferred. Still testing.

Comment: That wouldn't surprise me at all-it may be controllable though.